# Convert natural language to Math Logic

Tags: logic

This is the expression: "Set B goes when Set A does not go"

I wrote it like this: B and !A. But, I found the solution to be !A => B. Why is my solution not correct? I think it says the same thing, but in math logic it does not.

Comment: What does it mean for a set to "go"?

Comment: "B when A" is "if A, then B". You have "B when not A"; thus....

Answer (score 0):

Your question involves the difference between logical "and" and implication, which is an important distinction in logic. The implication "$p \Rightarrow q$" is only ever false when $p$ is true and $q$ is false. Logical "and" ($\wedge$) is only ever true when both are true. If you draw the truth tables, you'll see that the two differences between the two occur when $p$ is false.

So you're half right - it is the same thing when $p$ is true, but only then.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that "to go" is a [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)) function and it is immaterial that $A$ and $B$ are sets. If this is not the case, please let clarify what you mean. Your confusion seems to be about the meaning of logical operators ($\wedge, \Rightarrow,\ldots$), in particular, what truth-value is assigned to the desired sentence 
when $A$ "goes". Denote "to go" by the function $G(x)=\begin{cases}\text{true},& x\text{ "goes"}\\\text{false},& x\text{ "does not go"}\\\end{cases}$. Then, the expression $G(B)\wedge \neg G(A)$ would exclusively be true when $B$ "goes" but $A$ does not. Your second expression, $\neg G(A)\Rightarrow G(B)$ would be true in that case but would be **also** be true in the case that $A$ "goes". See the combined truth tables below.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
G(A)&G(B)&G(B)\wedge \neg G(A)&\neg G(A)\Rightarrow G(B)
\\ \hline
\color{blue}{\text{true}} & \color{blue}{\text{true}} & \text{false} & \color{blue}{\text{true}}
\\ \hline
\color{blue}{\text{true}} & \text{false} & \text{false} & \color{blue}{\text{true}}
\\ \hline
\text{false} & \color{blue}{\text{true}} & \color{blue}{\text{true}} & \color{blue}{\text{true}}
\\ \hline
\text{false} & \text{false} & \text{false} & \text{false}
\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

In a sense, "true" can mean "not falsified". The expression with "and" (column 3) explicitly states that unless both cases are satisfied, the expression is false. Conversely, the expression *"if $A$ does not go then $B$ goes"* (column 4) merely says that if we were given the premise *"$A$ does not go"*, we would be certain that $B$ goes. But if the premise were **false** (i.e., $A$ "goes"), we would effectively be outside of the scope of the expression, so whether or not $B$ "goes" has no impact on the expression's truth value. In other words, the statement would be [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) since the conclusion does not falsify the expression when we aren't given the premise.

I think your original natural language statement (using "when") was poorly expressed since it does not differentiate between these cases.